# Does a Lie algebra reproduce its Lie group?

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras

If I have Lie group and don't have its product law but know its Lie algebra then could I reproduce the product law globally? Or at least in the vicinity of identity?

More precisely if I consider two specific elements of the group, say $A=e^{a^iE_i}$ and $B=e^{b^iE_i}$ where $E_i$ s are a basis for the Lie algebra and I know $a_i$ and $b_i$ as given constants then could I compute $c_i$ where

$$AB=C=e^{c^iE_i}$$  from the Lie algebra structure constants?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baker-Campbell-Hausdorff_formula

Answer (score 3):

Yes, if the group is simply connected. In particular any two Lie groups with the same Lie algebra have the same universal cover, so are isomorphic in a neighborhood of the identity.